# Changing column values of a row based on other values in it

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, dataframe 1 has multiple repeating values, dataframe 2 indicates the category of these values. I would like to add this category for all my values in dateframe 1 in an additional column, something like `if(df1[i,1] = df2[,1]) {df1[i,2] = df2[,2]}`. For example, if `df1[i,1] = 2` and in df2, 2 & "b" are in the same row: `df1[i,2] = "b"` for all rows in df1 with 2 in its first column.

Here's a small SRS to fiddle with.

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame("v"= sample(1:3, size = 10, replace=T), "category"=rep("",10))
df2 <- data.frame("v"= 1:3,"c"= c("a","b", "c"))

#    v category
# 1  3         
# 2  3         
# 3  3         
# 4  2         
# 5  3         
# 6  2         
# 7  2         
# 8  2         
# 9  3         
# 10 1
```

Comment: You can remove `category` from `df1` and join on `v`: `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, "v")`

Comment: Here is a version of andrew_reece comment: `left_join(df1, df2, by="v") %>% 
    unite(category, c)`

Comment: Or use `df1$category <- tibble::deframe(df2)[df1$v]`